# adding tasks to pinned websites in ie9

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

how can i add tasks to windows 7 jumplist of pinned websites like there are tasks added to facebook and twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can view my post at http://nitin07sharma.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<META name="msapplication-task" content="name=Task 1;action-uri=http://host/Page1.html;icon-uri=http://host/icon1.ico"/>
```

The [Pinned Sites: Windows 7 Desktop Integration with Internet Explorer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article on MSDN seemingly provides all the information you need to fully get started with pinned sites.

The important gotcha is that the icon-uri *is* required. I assumed you could get away with not putting that at all and there would just be an empty space, but that's not the case.

For better or worse, the icon also has to be an ico file - a png won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of tasks you can add to a pinned site,
You can add static tasks or dynamic tasks
Static tasks are described in the blog post mentioned by Blazen, you can have up to 5 items on a static jump list.
There is a nice summary of how to pin your site and add a Jump List with tasks at [BuildMyPinnedSite](http://buildmypinnedsite.com/en-CA)
If you choose Jump lists and choose look at the code you will see code examples on how to use meta tags to add static jump lists and also code examples using Javascript for dynamic jump lists.
You can have both static and dynamic jump lists on the same site. 
I also wrote a couple of blogs talking about how to update a static jump list and [how to update a dynamic jump list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/08/08/how-do-you-update-a-pinned-site-in-ie9-part-2.aspx)

By the way, someone mentioned you need a .ico file for your favicon, check out [XiconEditor](http://www.xiconeditor.com/) a website that helps you create .ico files for pinned sites from your .JPG or .GIF files

Hope that helps!